# unarchiveObjectWithFile returns NSArray

Tags: iphone

I am working on NSKeyArchive and running into the problem... What I am having so far is

```
1.-(BOOL)archiveItem
2.{
3.    NSString *path = [self findPath];
4.    if ([NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:items toFile:wishListPath])
5.    {
6.        return YES;
7.    }else{
8.        return NO;
9.    }
10.}
11.-(BOOL)unarchiveItem
12.{
13.    NSString *path = [self findPath];
14.    self.items = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
15.    NSLog(@"Class of items is %@",[self.items class]);
16.    if (self.items == nil)
17.        return NO;
18.    else
19.           return YES;
20.}
```

In my header file, items is declared like

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *items;
```

However, line 15 shows that type of *items* is *NSArray* ( not NSMutablArray)

Does anyone have an idea about this one,please help. All comments are welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your `-(BOOL)unarchiveItem`

```
self.items = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

to

```
self.items = [[[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

change your declaration

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *items;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;
```

Comment: it did not work then.. I got this *-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6f26af0*

Comment: yeah when I change the to retain. It works like a charm...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you archive any object (mutable or immutable)...after unarchiving you will always get an "immutable" copy , so like X Slash wrote..obtain a mutable copy of the array..!!